# How do I handle "WARNING: You may not have a high enough lockable memory limit, see ulimit -l"?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, full-node, linux, system-requirements, operating-system

Upon running `monero-wallet-cli` after a fresh master build of `Monero 'Boron Butterfly' (v0.14.1.0-5fbfa8a)` I received the message:

> `WARNING: You may not have a high enough lockable memory limit, see ulimit -l`.

I tried it out.

`$ ulimit -l
64`

The `64` refers to KB.  I'm not sure what to do though.  I have about 8 GB of RAM.  `htop` reflects usage of `307M/7.72G`. This Linux box doesn't do much else besides act as a node. Should I increase the operating system's ability to lock more RAM?  How far should I go?  What are the consequences of making such a change?  Can I make the increase only available to `monerod` or `monero-wallet-cli`?

Answer (score 3):

I have 131072 kB and don't get any locking issues here. It may be much more than needed.
If you don't know what to do, I suggest trying twice what you have now, and see if that fixes the warning. If not, double again, etc. The more unswappable memory you have, the less leeway your OS has in choosing what to swap out when more memory is needed. If you do this in a particular shell, I think the change only applies to that shell and its children (or that's what the man page claims, but you probably saw that already).

Comment: Yes I can confirm this. On Linux, `ulimit` is per-process, which means if you set it inside a shell, it applies to that shell and its children. There is also a command `prlimit` which you can use to set the memlock limit for another process.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone, I had to change the limits by adding a line to `/etc/security/limits.conf`. For `<domain>` I put my username for the linux user that is using the wallet, for `<type>` I put `hard`, for `<item>` I put `memlock` and for `<value>` I put `2048`. I think a minimum of `1024` was needed in my case.

Reboot and now it becomes possible to set `ulimit -l` for the (non-root) user, by doing `ulimit -l 2048`. You could alternatively add a second line into `/etc/security/limits.conf` where `<type>` is `soft` to set that as the default.